# SIMPLE Collision Detection Java

Tags: java, collision

I have checked out the following link:

http://www.ehow.com/how_12134402_detect-rectangle-collision-java.html

I have made the 2 rectangles around my player and house but am confused about what my if statement should look like, I have a boolean set on x meaning if my rectangles intersect x will return true so I know I start with

```
if(x=true){
    //what to type in here for my collision?
}
```

This collision is required for my 2D state change game, I have a player that moves around with key inputs and a house on the map, I want my player not to be able to walk through the house.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your house a rectangle? Is your player a rectangle? The formula for collision detection should perform "exactly the same"* with floats as it does with integers.

*There are some things you'll have to look out for with floating point numbers but getting started is identical to the article's formula.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but math on floats works the same as math on ints, there is just a precision difference.  Can't you just take the example and convert all the places they used an int with a float?

Comment: @CodeChimp There is more than a precision difference, there is an error on the computer representation of a float.  Which means that two items that touch when represented by floats may have values that don't touch, touch, or overlap, depending on the history of math operations performed to achieve the result.  This means you need to make your algorithms account for non-precise inputs.  It's like asking if 2 +/- 0.02 overlaps 1.9 +/- 0.02.  Not as simple as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

use `Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,w,h))` to define your collision box.

Then check

```
rect.contains(x,y);
```

or

```
bool isCollision = rectOne.intersects(rectTwo);
```

Or more complete example

```
// returns true at the first collision
// returns false if no collision with none of the houses
Rectangle2D.Double player = new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,w,h);
Rectangle2D.Double[] houses = map.getHouseBounds();
boolean isAnyCollision = false;
int i = 0;
while (!isAnyCollision && cnt < houses.length) {
   isAnyCollision = player.intersects(houses[i]);
}
return isAnyCollision;
```

Comment: I typed in the question incorrectly, sorry please check it over now, its been edited. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I updated, too; But now your question is confusing, isCollision is what you wanted to know?

Comment: @BenDover I updated code, please check if helps, and if helped accept with checkbox

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have a problem with the code, the map.getHouseBounds keeps coming up with an error under map, it says it needs a field to be built. Also in the code is player and map not supposed to be the other way round? I mean I thought that java got the bounds for the player and the house on the map was input with coordinates. Also, will this collision detection work the way I want it to, I mean will it stop the player from entering the house?

Comment: this can notbbe answered in the scope of the original question. i cannpt developp your game. usually you check if the player collides with the terrain/houses. because you have less players than houses. you have to build both, the player bounds, and the house bounds(=rectangles if simple house). you build that from the house coordinates, and from the player center + player image width, heigth